# Pyenv unable to detect installed python versions on MacOS Catalina

Tags: python, macos, zshrc, pyenv

I have MacOS Catalina and I went ahead and did a `brew install` for the latest version of `python` 3.8.5. Then I discovered `pyenv` and installed that as well. I followed the steps on https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#basic-github-checkout from number 3 but still can't see any python versions in `pyenv`.

I have both .zprofile and .zshrc files and am wondering if that's causing issues. Here's my `echo $PATH` -

```
/Users/pq0252/.pyenv/shims/shims:/Users/pq0252/.pyenv/shims/shims:/Users/pq0252/.pyenv/shims:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Here's the pyenv version output:

```
pyenv versions
* system (set by /Users/pq0252/.pyenv/shims/version)
```

Here's the `.zprofile` contents -

```
 #Setting PATH for Python 3.8.   
 #The original version is saved in .zprofile.pysave.   
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:${PATH}"   
export PATH
```

Here's the `.zshrc` contents (this seems to be repeating the `if` condition, even though I only added it once which I am thinking has something to do with the step 3 on `pyenv` github where we are appending to it?).

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv/shims"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT:$PATH"
export PIPENV_PYTHON="$PYENV_ROOT/python"
echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n  eval "$(pyenv init -)"\n$
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
```

Should I remove entries in `.zshrc` and instead add everything to `.zprofile` or is there something else I'm missing? `python3 --version` does show 3.8.5.

Comment: Have you installed pyenv version by running `pyenv install python_version_to_install`?

Comment: @harryghgim I used `brew` to install it, followed from here - https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#installation

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I see when I run `pyenv versions`

```
➜  ~ pyenv versions
* system (set by /Users/gwanghyeongim/.pyenv/version)
  3.7.6
  3.7.7
```

And this is what I have in my `.zshrc` file.

```
# pyenv config
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
```

Your `PYENV_ROOT` and `PATH` in `.zshrc` looks odd. According to the installation guide, they should looke something like above. Make them like above.

It seems instead of running `echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n  eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi' >> ~/.zshrc` in terminal, you put it in `.zshrc` directly. Remove the code block starting `echo -e` and run the code in the terminal instead. Then your `.zshrc` will look like something above.

Now try running `pyenv install version_to_install`, where version_to_install is python you want to install with pyenv. For exmaple

```
pyenv install 3.7.7
```

Then it will install the specific version. After it's installed, run `pyenv versions` again and see if you see the installed python version too in the list.

Comment: So I had already installed python 3.8.5 using `brew` and I just want `pyenv` to refer to it, I don't want to re-install it.

Comment: I get `/Users/pq0252/.pyenv/shims:/Users/pq0252/.pyenv/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` in `echo $PATH` after making the changes you suggested but I still don't see `pyenv versions` showing the python version.

Comment: @linuxNoob Installing `pyenv` with `brew` and installing a separate python version with `pyenv install python_version` are two different things. I'm telling you to run `pyenv install`(which will install a separate python version) command, not `brew install`(which will install pyenv software itself)

Comment: I'm saying I installed python 3.8.5 using `brew` before I installed `pyenv` using `brew`.

Comment: if you want to see 3.8.5 when you run `pyenv versions`, you need to install it using `pyenv install`. System python versions(version you already have before installing pyenv) will appear just as `system`. I'm using python 3.8.5 installed by brew, and this is my system python

Comment: sounds like I can safely assume that the version is 3.8.5 then?

Comment: @linuxNoob Yes. `pyenv` has nothing to do with referring to system python version. What you see when you run `python --version` is your python version installed. If you want to see where is that python version is referring, run `which python3`, then it will show the python version interpreter path something like this: `/Users/gwanghyeongim/.pyenv/shims/python3`

Comment: I was under the impression that `pyenv` would change the system version as I need it, sounds like not though. Not sure how it will be useful then.

Comment: @linuxNoob Not so unless you install separate python version to use it with separate dependency like `virtualvenv` for specific python version project.

Comment: so if I install something which needs python say `Airflow`, will it by default use the python version on my system? On my system `python --version` is 2.7.16

Comment: It sounds like `pyenv` is useful only if I use it to install python, if not it's pointless.

Comment: You can set different version either globally by running `pyenv global python_version` or locally in your project folder by running `pyenv local python_version`. `Airflow` is installable as python package, so if you set a specific python version where `Airflow` to be installed on and make `virtualvenv` or `venv` and install `Airflow` on that virtual environment, pyenv can serve your needs.

Comment: `pyenv global 3.8.5` gives me version 3.8.5 not installed. I'm not sure what `virtualenv` does, need to look into that.

Comment: I suggest you look into python dependencies like `virtualvenv`, `venv` or `mkvirtualenv` along with pyenv. Setting python version is pyenv's job, and separating projects where python packages are installed on is dependencies' job.

Comment: Ensure you have python version installed first before running `pyenv global` or `pyenv local`. Besides, you don't need `pyenv global 3.8.5` since your default python version is 3.8.5 globally unless specified otherwise by you.

Comment: `pyenv global` gives system but `python --version` gives 2.7.16

Comment: What about `python3 --version`?

Comment: That gives 3.8.5